# displaying JSON Data one by one

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data like this

```
[
"00-00-02":"first one",
"00-00-04":"the second",
"00-00-09":"third",
.
.
]
```

How I can display for example: `first one` in the specified time `00-00-02` and then display the next at its time `00-00-04`?
**Note**: I should do that using javascript

Comment: jsonvar["00-00-02"] (the var that holds JSON) should return "first one" so I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: @MihaRekar the problem is timing this texts.

Comment: I still don't understand. What timing?

Comment: @MihaRekar Ok, I have a translation for video and i want to display each text at specific time.

Comment: just as a side note; take a look at momentjs.com as well. Very useful for handling dates in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Geek Num 88 suggests the right way to do it. In such cases usually unix timestamp is used. In case you can't change the json, you can do something like this

```
var data = {
"00-00-02":"first one",
"00-00-04":"the second",
"00-00-09":"third"
}
var timeout;
var start = new Date();
function showIt(){
    var now = new Date();
    var diff = now - start;
    var hh = Math.floor(diff / 600000);
    hh = (hh < 10)?"0" + hh : hh;
    var mm = Math.floor((diff % 3600000) / 60000);
    mm = (mm < 10)?"0" + mm : mm;
    var ss = Math.floor((diff % 60000 ) / 1000); 
    ss = (ss < 10)?"0" + ss : ss;

    if(data[hh + "-" + mm + "-" + ss]){
       console.log(data[hh + "-" + mm + "-" + ss]);
    }

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(showIt, 1000);
}


showIt();
```

Comment: LOL Greek - thats funny - just Geek is fine

Answer (score 1):

if you use UNIX time you can do the comparison rather easy - for instance

```
var data = {
   "1349598808" : "first one",
   "1349598845" : "the second",
   "1349599400" : "third"
};

var now;
var seconds;

setInterval(function(){
     now = new Date();
     seconds = Math.round(now.getTime()/1000);
     if(data[seconds] != undefined)
     {
          console.log(data[seconds]);
          // OR 
          // PrototypeJS
          $("mydiv").update(data[seconds]);
          // OR
          // jquery
          $("#mydiv").html(data[seconds]);
     }
},1000);
​
```

Comment: thank you, but how i can get time like this, i searched about that.. but i didn't understand anything!

Comment: what script is generating your page or ajax call? Most languages can convert standard "human" time to UNIX time

Comment: No language, i get the time from stored data in SQL Server Database, but i can change the time column if you told me how i can do that?

Comment: I think this should do it  http://mysql.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-convert-a-sql-server-datetime-value-to-a-unix-timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

do you have an array of just json? if you have json the following will work:

```
var data = {
  "00-00-02":"first one",
  "00-00-04":"the second",
  "00-00-09":"third"
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  var val = data[key];
  console.log("the " + val + " had a time of " + key + " seconds")
});
```

Comment: You didn't solve my problem, i want to display each text at the specified time.

Comment: You have to add more details to your question. It doesn't say anything about videos. However, take a look at [popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/). It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `setTimeout(fn, time)` function to call "first-one", "the-second" ... after a calculated interval. The pseudocode would be something like

```
data = ["00-00-02":"first one", "00-00-04":"the second", "00-00-09":"third",...];
//using [key: value] notation
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    eventTime = timeInMilliSeconds(data[i].key);
    setTimeout(printMyMessage(data[i].value, eventTime);
}
```

or you could maybe call the `setTimeout()` for `data[i]` in the function call `printMyMessage()` for `data[i-1]`. The second argument to the `setTimeout()` function in that case would be the time diff between `data[i]` and `data[i-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that video subtitles are already a thing, and you don't need to reimplement them.

You could go for the `track` element from HTML5, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/, or if you need more compatability, you could use popcorn.js: http://popcornjs.org/.

If you don't want to do that, then just use a window.setTimeout to display each one.